# Json extra fields

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I created this working code which is storing data from an api to a json file
 based on yesterday's date.

```
$filedate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
    $yesterday = date('Y-m-d 00:00',strtotime("-1 days"));
    $today = date('Y-m-d 23:59',strtotime("-1 days"));

    try{

        $soccer=new XMLSoccer("API KEY");
        $soccer->setServiceUrl("http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballData.asmx");
        /*  $result=$soccer->GetLiveScore();*/
        $result=$soccer->GetFixturesByDateInterval(array( "startDateString"=> "$yesterday" ,"endDateString"=> "$today"));            
        var_dump($result);

        $fp = fopen( "/var/www/public_html/domain/$filedate.json","w+");
        fwrite($fp,json_encode($result));
        fclose($fp);
    }
    catch(XMLSoccerException $e){
        echo "XMLSoccerException: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

The code above stores this json data in the file :

```
{
Match: [
{
Id: "346528",
Date: "2015-07-15T12:00:00+00:00",
League: "Chinese Super League",
Round: "19",
HomeTeam: "Guangzhou Evergrande",
HomeTeam_Id: "1108",
HomeGoals: "0",
AwayTeam: "Henan Jianye",
AwayTeam_Id: "1100",
AwayGoals: "0",
Time: "Not started",
Location: "Tianhe Stadium",
HomeTeamYellowCardDetails: { },
AwayTeamYellowCardDetails: { },
HomeTeamRedCardDetails: { },
AwayTeamRedCardDetails: { }
},
{
Id: "346527",
Date: "2015-07-15T11:45:00+00:00",
League: "Chinese Super League",
Round: "19",
HomeTeam: "Shanghai Greenland Shenhua",
HomeTeam_Id: "1107",
HomeGoals: "0",
AwayTeam: "Beijing Guoan",
AwayTeam_Id: "1098",
AwayGoals: "0",
Time: "Not started",
Location: "Hongkou Football Stadium",
HomeTeamYellowCardDetails: { },
AwayTeamYellowCardDetails: { },
HomeTeamRedCardDetails: { },
AwayTeamRedCardDetails: { }
},
}
```

Right now I need to add some extra fields for each match, for example if HomeTeam = Real Madrid , add extra field HomeTeamShort = RMD etc. This should be done dynamically because I have to create IF's for each away and home team.

Somebody can help how can i do this ?

Comment: You want to add extra code in where? In json file? Can you give the result of var_dump($result); here?

Comment: Hi, the var_dump ($result); it's a xml (api only return xml) then i encode in json exactly with the same data : <XMLSOCCER.COM>
<Match>
<Id>353268</Id>
<Date>2015-07-18T13:30:00+00:00</Date>
<League>Ekstraklasa</League>
<Round>1</Round>
<Spectators/>
<HomeTeam>Ruch Chorzow</HomeTeam>
<HomeTeam_Id>437</HomeTeam_Id>
<AwayTeam>Gornik Leczna</AwayTeam>
<AwayTeam_Id>1271</AwayTeam_Id>
<Time>45'</Time>
<HomeGoals>0</HomeGoals>
<AwayGoals>1</AwayGoals>
</Match> (...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to decode your json

```
$array = json_decode($result);
```

Get the Match array

```
$arr = $array->Match;
```

Now loop through all the objects (i.e.) and do whatever necessary

```
foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    //do whatever you want to do with that object
    if($item->HomeTeam == "Real Madrid") {
       $item->HomeTeamShort = "RMD";
    }
}

print_r($arr); //Now $arr is the required result you wanted to have

//you can also convert your array back json 
$arr2 = json_encode($arr);
```

Please let me know if you wanted something else and I will change my code to address your need.

Thank you.

*** ADDITIONAL HELP WITH EXAMPLE ***

Check if you have put the variables and arrays of object properly before running the loop. Since I can't see what you have really done in your code and what your line numbers are, I am pasting a full dummy code along with outputs, *please compare it with your own code and you should be able to get the proper output*.

```
<?php
//let's take an example json data
$result = '{"Match":
                [
                    {"name":"Tom", "age":22},
                    {"name":"Jerry", "age":20},
                    {"name":"Hank", "age":25}
                ]           
            }';

$array = json_decode($result);
$arr = $array->Match;
```

Let's print the array once before processing

```
print_r($arr); //Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Tom [age] => 22 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Jerry [age] => 20 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Hank [age] => 25 ) )
```

Now do the loop thing and add whatever property you need to whichever object you want

```
foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    //do whatever you want to do with that object
    if($item->name == "Jerry") {
       $item->color = "Brown";
    }
}
```

Now if you print the array again you will see *Color Brown has been added to Jerry*

```
print_r($arr); //Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Tom [age] => 22 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Jerry [age] => 20 [color] => Brown ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Hank [age] => 25 ) )
```

Convert your array back json if you want

```
$arr2 = json_encode($arr);
```

Now, check the json, you will also see the **Color Brown** there **against Jerry**

```
var_dump($arr2); //string(92) "[{"name":"Tom","age":22},{"name":"Jerry","age":20,"color":"Brown"},{"name":"Hank","age":25}]"

?>
```

This is step by step analysis and explanation of this code. As you can see I am not getting any undefined object error. So, try copy pasting my above code and if you can replicate the same error, then it will be easy for me to understand what is causing your bug.

I have also made a [PHPFiddle Link here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c8ky-895n), you can check the code and run it also there.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Suman, Thank you very much for your help ;) , i'm getting 2 errors when i use your code : Trying to get property of non-object in on line 22 and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  on line 23 , at first i try to fix because you never save the changed $item back to $arr and i change foreach($arr as &$item) but keep showing the same errors , any idea ? one more time thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @SaulHenriques, welcome :) I have added a detailed explanation to my answer and also added the output. I am not getting any object undefined error. See if you have properly used array of objects. Or if you replicate your error with my code, i will be very happy to help you. But since I can't see your code, your line numbers are no use to me. :P and you can always thank me my selecting/upvoting my answer ;) :D All the Best :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, don't solve my problem but make me progress(i'm getting close )

Maybe it's my mistake, because i don't provide some important things

So.. i test your code on phpfiddle and it works, and works mostly because you have the json directly on the code, in my project i need to open the file.json from the server, and with your code even adapting a few things , i get some errors, so ... i change your code a little bit :

```
    <?php

$json_url = "http://getinstagoal.com/2015-07-20.json";
    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $links = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($links["Match"] as $key=>$val) {
        if($val['HomeTeam'] == "Palmeiras") {

            $val['HomeTeamshor'] = "RMD";

    }
}




//you can also convert your array back json 
$arr2 = json_encode($links);

//print the json, you will also see the Color Brown there against Jerry
var_dump($arr2); //string(92) "[{"name":"Tom","age":22},{"name":"Jerry","age":20,"color":"Brown"},{"name":"Hank","age":25}]"


?>
```

with that code i was able to get the right data, i try with some echo and etc.

however the file update didn't work even running php as root on the server, i check and "if" works (i test it with "echo") i try with file_put_content didn't work, the only way that i successfully do add something to the json file was creating and array of the content but that will rewrite the entire file. Any idea about that ?

Other thing, i will need to do "if" 8 items per match something like

```
if($val['HomeTeam'] == "Real Madrid") {

            $val['HomeTeamshort'] = "RMD";
 }

if($val['AwayTeam'] == "Barcelona") {

            $val['AwayTeamshort'] = "FCB";
 }
```

for more than 1300 (it should compare in the file, usually it's 20 games per day, not that much)

What is the most efficient way that i have to do this "ifs" to each match ?

Thank you @Suman